Notification Page didn't show any new notifications
I am trying to create a website with laravel, I have mostly created the whole website, but when I'm trying to create the notification, well it did show, but it didn't show any notification. The supposedly shown notification is new follower, new article from followed user, article being liked, article being commented and the comment being replied to
NotificationController
class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $notifications = $user->notifications;
        $title = 'Notifications';

        return view('pages.notifications', compact('notifications', 'title'));
    }

}

Notifications
class FollowNotification extends Notification
{
    public function __construct(User $user, User $follower)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->follower = $follower;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'You have a new follower!',
            'follower_name' => $this->follower->name,
        ];
    }
}

notifications.blade.php

    @if ($notifications->isEmpty())
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            You have no notifications.
        </div>
    @else
    <div class="list-group">
        @foreach ($notifications as $notification)
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                    @if ($notification->type == 'follow')
                        <i class="fas fa-user-plus me-3" style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                    @endif
                    <div>
                        <h5 class="mb-1">
                            @if ($notification->type == 'follow')
                                {{ $notification->data['follower_id']->name }} started following you
                    <form action="{{ route('markAsRead', ['id' => $notification->id]) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Mark as read</button>
                    

I have tried to change the codes, but it'd result error in the other function. I have tried to debug it and check the laravel.log, but it didn't show any error for the notification not showing. With this, I kind of suspecting that it was the data that didn't correctly passed to the view or the blade just won't receive any notifiable. Can someone give me pointers?
